# SVN Log Get revision number from specific commit

Tags: java, svn, build

Im using Subversion on a linux system

Im trying to get the revision numbers of specific commits based upon their commit logs (message).

When a revision is updated with the value of Y I run a script to check to if any revisions contain that text, however I cant retrieve the actual revision number. I want to  capture this number to target specific files to merge.

this is the log script Im using

svn log  [SVN_URL] -v  | grep  'Y'

and this is what returned when run

`<Tested></Tested>`, but not the revision number.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. If your search-string is part of commit-message, `-v` is not needed (it adds only filelist for revision)
2. If you use SVN 1.8, you can have log+grep in one command `svn log ... --search Y`
3. In order to get revision from (filtered by keyword) log, you have to use something like `| grep "|" | gawk {print $1}` after `svn log`